# How to apply a VLOOKUP formula that references another workbook using openpyxl in python?

Tags: python, excel, loops, excel-formula, openpyxl

I have :

1. A base template excel file
2. A list of excel files

The process :

1. Using a for loop iterate through every file in the list.
2. For every file in the for loop, fill the base template based on the file's content using a
   VLOOKUP function.
3. For every file in the for loop, save the filled base template with the name of the file in the
   current iteration.

The problem :

**The VLOOKUP formula does not apply to each file in the iteration and it shows as a blank cell in the file.**

The code :

```
  def aiakos() :
    import openpyxl as op
    import os, glob
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import  

    outpath = r"C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_OUT" ## Output path
    inpath = r"C:\Users\pallist\AROTRON_IN" ## Input path
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join(inpath, "*.xlsx")) ## All INPUT files
    wb0 = load_workbook(os.path.join(outpath, "template.xlsx")) ## Template file
    sheet0 = wb0['Φύλλο1'] ## Template sheet


    for f in files :  ## For each input file
        fwb=load_workbook(f)  ## Open each input file
        fsheet=fwb['Sheet1']  ## Open first sheet of each input file
        base_f = os.path.basename(f)
        i =2

        for row in sheet0['N2:N416']: ## For rows N2-N416  
             for cell in row:
                 formula     = f"=VLOOKUP(A{i},[{base_f}]Sheet1!'!$A:$P,16,0)".format(cell.row)
                 cell.value  = formula             
                 print(f"N{i}, {formula}")
                 i += 1
        for row in fsheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=fsheet.max_row, min_col=14, max_col=14): 
            for cell in row :
                sheet0.cell(row=i,column=17).value = cell.value
                print(cell.value)
                i += 1
                wb0.save(os.path.join(outpath,os.path.basename(f)))
```

Comment: You should be updating your original question instead of reposting it.

Comment: Thank you for your input. As you see the scope of the new question is much broader than the older question, as it contains an inquiry about the VLOOKUP function which the previous one did not address.

Comment: The question and the code looks much the same to me and it seems to contains the same mistakes that others have pointed out.

Comment: In that case it seems that I was unsuccesful in implementing the previous corrections. Could you please point the mistakes in the posted code? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I ran you code and identified 2 mistakes and 1 performance problem.

1. The formula you have for `VLOOKUP()`. There is an (I guess unintentional) single quote `'` after `Sheet1!`
2. In between the two INSIDE FOR loops, you should reset `i` back to 2. Without that, the 17th column data starts way below.
3. The save that you have is inside the second for loop. This will save each time a row is written. So, this is really slow and unnecessary. You should really do it after the for loop runs, so that you save all changes once...

I am ONLY showing the FOR loops below. You can replace this in your code. See if this works...

```
for f in files :  ## For each input file
    fwb=load_workbook(f)  ## Open each input file
    fsheet=fwb['Sheet1']  ## Open first sheet of each input file
    base_f = os.path.basename(f)
    i =2
    print(f)
    for row in sheet0['N2:N416']: ## For rows N2-N416 of template file - not saving
        for cell in row:
            ### Change 1 - Removed the single quote
            formula = f"=VLOOKUP(A{i},[{base_f}]Sheet1!$A:$P,16,0)".format(cell.row)
            cell.value  = formula
#            print(f"N{i}, {formula}")
            i += 1
    ### Change 2 - Reset i to 2, so that this data starts from row 2
    i=2
    for row in fsheet.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=fsheet.max_row, min_col=14, max_col=14): #Input file
        for cell in row :
            sheet0.cell(row=i,column=17).value = cell.value
       #     print(cell.value)
            i += 1
    ### Change 3 - Moved the save outside the for loop - it will run once for each input file
    wb0.save(os.path.join(outpath,os.path.basename(f)))
```

Comment: I ran your code and I noticed two things, one good and one bad. The good news is that the cell of the formula no longer is empty, meaning that the formula is generally applied properly. The bad news is that I get a #REF error in the VLOOKUP formula, on the {base_f} part

Comment: The error : =VLOOKUP(A2;#REF!$A:$P;16;0)

Comment: It just means that the file `base_f` is not found, which is probably because you are using basename and not the full name including path. I am not seeing the error. Try replace the `base_f` by the variable that has the full input file name... is that `f`? Which file should the VLOOKUP formula be checking in - `f` I am assuming?